# ChartJS - Graphic with multiple values on the same date

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm trying to build a [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/) graph. Before I had a line graph with 1 value per date. But now my requirements changed and I need two values per date (a maximum value and a minimum value) like he following:

**Before**
[image: what I had]
**Pretended**
[image: what I want]

I tried using a `scatter` graph following [this example](https://codepen.io/devil-geek/pen/KrQWBP), but apparently it doesn't work with dates and ended up like this:
[image]

**Code I tried**

```
...
$.each(grafico, function (index1, value) {
                           console.log("########################################");
                           console.log(value);

                           data = value.x.map(function (a) { return a.x; });
                           dates = value.x.map(function (a) { return a.date });

                           var myData = {
                               datasets: [{
                                   label: "Dataset #1",
                                   backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                                   borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                                   borderWidth: 2,
                                   hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
                                   hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                                   data: [
                                       x => data,
                                       y => dates
                                   ]
                               }]
                           };

                           var myOption = {
                               scales: {
                                   yAxes: [{
                                       stacked: true,
                                       gridLines: {
                                           display: true,
                                           color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
                                       }
                                   }],
                                   xAxes: [{
                                       gridLines: {
                                           display: true,
                                           color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
                                       }
                                   }]
                               },
                               elements: {
                                   line: {
                                       tension: .1, // bezier curves
                                   }
                               }
                           };

                           /*$.each(data, function (index, value) {
                               dataLabels[index] = 'X' + (index + 1);
                           });*/
                       
                           window['ctx' + index + index1] = document.getElementById('chart' + value.cellId + value.component).getContext('2d');
                           window['myChart' + index + index1] = new Chart(window['ctx' + index + index1], {
                               type: 'scatter',
                               options: myOption,
                               data: myData
                           });
                       });
...
```

**My data looks like this**
[image]

**PS:** for simplicity reasons I was first trying to add just one value per date and then move on from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add another dataset.

```
let data1 = value.x[0]; // first set of data
let data2 = value.x[1]; // second set of data


datasets: [
    {
        label: "Dataset #1",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        data: data1,
        parsing: { // what values to use from data1
            yAxisKey: 'x',
            xAxiskey: 'date',
        },
    },
    {
        label: "Dataset #2",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        data: data2,
        parsing: { // what values to use from data2
            yAxisKey: 'x',
            xAxiskey: 'date',
        },
    }
],
```

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I was thinking If I drew only one line I couldn't get the intended output, and I was kinda missing the point I could just draw two lines instead. Thanks.